# sendevent in android

Tags: android, adb

I saw in some documentation that **getevent** gives some hexadecimal values and while passing to **sendevent** we need to convert the values to decimal. My question is if the value is **ffffffff** in hexadecimal what value should we pass in sendevent? I tried passing -1 and 4294967295 but did not get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

The send event parameters are defined in [toolbox/sendevent.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.2.1_r1/toolbox/sendevent.c) as:

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    __u16 type;
    __u16 code;
    __s32 value;
};
```

and the command line argument is converted using `atoi()`:

```
event.value = atoi(argv[4]);
```

I do not see why `-1` would not work. How are you checking if the command failed?

Comment: I am using set of adb sendevent commands to generate a touch event on the screen (pseduo touch event). Before sending those commands I used getevent which gives me values in hex codes which I converted to decimal and passed it to sendevent. I found out that for ffffffff the value of 4294967295 must be passed and I was able to generate the touch event. Thank you :)